# ImportError: No module named numpy in Debian OS

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In my virtual environment on my debian machine, I am able to import numpy at the prompt But when I call it in a program it errors out.

I am looking over the net and they say to uninstall and re-install. I tried but novail.
Also, I am able to import it in python prompt but not when I call the script? Please help me out of this.

I am able to call successfully at the prompt:-

```
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project# python
    Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 13 2020, 08:44:45)
    [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import paramiko
    >>> import numpy
    >>> exit()
```

Here when I try to execute my program it errors out:-

```
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project# ./test_nump.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_nump.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project# cat test_nump.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy
print("test")
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project#
```

Comment: You have set your interpreter in your python file explicitly to `/usr/bin/python` which is not part of the virtual environment hence does not see the numpy module. You could try invoking your python explicitly using `python test_nump.py` or specify the interpreter in the shebang to your venv python installation although that's not portable, so just use the python command to invoke it

Comment: thank you very very much @pikaynu can u put it in answer. I shall mark it .. so that it helps someone else

Comment: what would the shebang path be exactly?(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project# echo $PATH
/root/my-project/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/root/my-project

Comment: Ok I tried with #!/usr/bin/env python worked! How is this logic. I have: (venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# which python
/root/my-project/venv/bin/python
AND $PATH --> /root/my-project/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/root/my-project What is this interpreted. Because in the $PATH there is no /usr/bin/"env" python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per request from the OP.

For any executable file, bash reads the first line with the `shebang` or `#!...` to extract the interpreter for the script. If it does not find the shebang, it will try to service the file type using the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and then use the relevant loading method. That's why running an ELF binary does not require you to specify the executor.

Now, virtual environments works by overriding your bash search path, i.e. when you type a command, where should it look. For example, if you have a binary name `ls` where should it find it to load from. It refers to your search path or the `$PATH` variable and scans the directories sequentially and stops at the first match. Virtual environment will prepend it's path to the `$PATH` when you do a `source .venv`. The `source` command simply tells your bash session to apply the bash directives from the `.venv` file.

In your source file, you have supplied the interpreter using the `shebang` directive to the global installation of python which does not have `numpy` in it's module list so it fails.

If you run it using `python script.py`, because the `$PATH` is overridden by virtual env, the shell will find the python version of virtual env first than the global one which has your numpy module.

Why does `/usr/bin/env python` work ? Because it's going to refer to your `$PATH` in your environment variable (which is modified by virtual env) and will find the correct python installation.

[image]